# Spring boot Groovy test does not see application.properties

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-boot, geb

I was testing my application with JUnit:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = PDK.class)
@WebAppConfiguration // does not run Tomcat
//@WebIntegrationTest // runs Tomcat
@DirtiesContext
public class WebControllersTest {
```

Then I wished to test it with Geb, which Groovy and wrote:

```
//@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=[PDK])
//@WebAppConfiguration
@WebIntegrationTest
@DirtiesContext
class GebMainpageSpec extends GebSpec {
```

Unfortunately, my beans which have `@Value` annotations started failing initialize.

How to fix?

Comment: You have to use `SpringApplicationConfiguration` else it won't work. You probably need to do some special setup to make it work, normally the `SpringApplicationConfiguration` triggers that

Comment: Ah, yes, you are exactly right!